# Exception: Method not found: Void .... C#

Tags: c#, methods

i am new in this and i have a problem. Sorry for my english.

I have a windows project and i have a library called "libPQR"; in there, i have a public method called "guardarPQR". In that method i define a SQL sentence and call a method for validate the datums; after that, i call a private method inside de library call "grabar" where i do the conexion to the database.

The problem is when i call the method "grabar",it caught an exception that it say: "method not found:'void libConexionBD.clsConexionBD.set_SQL(System.String)'."

I dont understand, because method grabar returns a bool type.

I show you the code:

```
public bool guardarPQR()
    {
        bool bandera;
            try
            {
                strSQL = "insert into PQR values('" + strDescripcion + "'," + intSistema + ",'" + string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dtfecha) + "', '" + string.Format("{0:HH:mm}", dthorainicio) + "', '" + string.Format("{0:HH:mm}", dthorafinalizacion) + "'," + intError + ")";

                if (!validar())
                    return false;


                bandera = grabar();
               return bandera;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strError = ex.Message;
                return false;
            }
```

And this is the other method:

```
        private bool grabar()
        {
            try
            {

                objCnx = new clsConexionBD();
                objCnx.SQL = strSQL;

                if (!objCnx.ConsultarValorUnico(false))
                {
                    objCnx = null;
                    return false;
                }

                intId = Convert.ToInt32(objCnx.Valor_Unico);

                objCnx.CerrarCnx();
                objCnx = null;

                return true;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strError = ex.Message;
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Thanks for the help.

This is the library: libconexionBD

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

//Referenciar y usar
using System.Data;//Facilita usar los objetos conectados y desconectados
using System.Data.SqlClient;//Objeto especializado para conexion a sql server //Commmon para oracle //SQLServer entrar a sqlserver y bajar drive para .net

//Referenciar y usar

using System.IO;

namespace libConexionBD
{
public class clsConexionBD
{
#region "Constructor"
    public clsConexionBD()
    {      
        blnHayCnx = false;
        objCnx = new SqlConnection();      //Para la Conexión
        objCmd = new SqlCommand();         //Para la Transacción
        objAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(); //Para la llenar el DataSet
        objDts = new DataSet();            //Para el DataSet
    }
#endregion

#region "Atríbutos"

    private string strCadenaCnx;       //Para la cadena de conexón a la BD
    private object objVrUnico;         //Para la captura y retorno del Vr. único(método: ConsultarValorUnico)) 
    private string strSQL;             //Para la sentencia SQL a ejecutarse en la BD
    private string strError;           //Para el mensaje de error
    private bool blnHayCnx;            //Para saber si hay o no Cnx a la BD
    private SqlConnection objCnx;      //Para el objeto Conexión
    private SqlCommand objCmd;         //Para el objeto Command (realiza la transacción)
    private SqlDataReader objReader;   //Para el objeto DataReader (contenedor de info)
    private SqlDataAdapter objAdapter; //Para el objeto DataAdapter (para llenar el DataSet, entre otros)
    private DataSet objDts;            //Para el objeto DataSet (contenedor de info)
#endregion

#region "Propiedades"
    public string SQL                     //Para ingresar la sentencia SQL a ejecutarse en la BD      
    { set { strSQL = value;    } }
    public object Valor_Unico             //Para retornar el valor obtenido al invocar el método:  ConsultarValorUnico
    { get { return objVrUnico; } }
    public SqlDataReader DataReader_Lleno //Para retornar el DataReader con la info obtenida al invocar el método: Consultar
    { get { return objReader;  } }
    public DataSet DataSet_Lleno          //Para retornar el DataSet con la info obtenida al invocar el método: LlenarDataSet
    { get { return objDts;     } }
    public string Error                   //Para retornar el mensaje de error
    { get { return strError;   } }
#endregion

#region "Métodos Privados"
    private bool GenerarCadenaCnx()
    {
        /*try
        {
            if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( strApp ) )
            {
                strError = "Sin Nombre de la aplicación";
                return false;
            }
            clsParametros objParams = new clsParametros();
            if ( ! objParams.GenerarCadenaCnx( strApp ) )
            {
                strError = objParams.Error;
                objParams = null;
                return false;
            }
            strCadenaCnx = objParams.CadenaCnx;
            objParams = null;
            return true;
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            strError = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }*/

        string[] parametros;
        string line;
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader("conexion.txt");

        try
        {
            line = r.ReadLine();

            parametros = line.Split(':');

            strCadenaCnx = "Data Source=" + parametros[0] + "\\" + parametros[1] + " ; Initial Catalog=PQR ; User ID=TUENLACETV ; PASSWORD=1234";
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strError = ex.Message;
            return false;

        }
    }
    private bool AbrirCnx()
    {
        if ( ! GenerarCadenaCnx() )
            return false;
        objCnx.ConnectionString = strCadenaCnx;
        try
        {
            objCnx.Open();
            blnHayCnx = true;
            return true;
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            strError = ex.Message;
            blnHayCnx = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
#endregion

#region "Métodos Públicos"
    public void CerrarCnx()
    {
        try
        {
            objCnx.Close();
            objCnx = null;
            blnHayCnx = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strError = "No se cerró o liberó la conexión, " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
    public bool Consultar( bool blnParametros )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( strSQL ) )
            {
                strError = "No definió la instrucción SQL";
                return false;
            }
            if ( ! blnHayCnx )
                if ( ! AbrirCnx() )
                    return false;

            //Preparar el Comando para ejecutar la transacción SQL en la BD
            objCmd.Connection = objCnx;
            objCmd.CommandText = strSQL;

            if (blnParametros)
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            else
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            objReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();  //Realizar la transacción en la BD
            return true;
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            strError = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool ConsultarValorUnico( bool blnParametros )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( strSQL ) )
            {
                strError = "No definió la instrucción SQL";
                return false;
            }
            if ( ! blnHayCnx )
                if ( ! AbrirCnx() )
                    return false;
            //Preparar el Comando para ejecutar la transacción SQL en la BD
            objCmd.Connection = objCnx;
            objCmd.CommandText = strSQL;
            if (blnParametros)
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            else
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            objVrUnico = objCmd.ExecuteScalar();  //Realizar la transacción en la BD
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strError = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool EjecutarSentencia( bool blnParametros )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(strSQL) )
            {
                strError = "No definió la instrucción SQL";
                return false;
            }
            if ( ! blnHayCnx )
                if ( ! AbrirCnx() )
                    return false;
            //Preparar el Comando para ejecutar la transacción SQL en la BD
            objCmd.Connection = objCnx;
            objCmd.CommandText = strSQL;
            if (blnParametros)
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            else
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   //Realizar la transacción en la BD
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strError = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool LlenarDataSet( bool blnParametros )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( strSQL ) )
            {
                strError = "No definió la instrucción SQL";
                return false;
            }
            if ( ! blnHayCnx )
                if ( ! AbrirCnx() )
                    return false;
            //Preparar el Comando para el DataAdapter
            objCmd.Connection = objCnx;
            objCmd.CommandText = strSQL;
            if (blnParametros)
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            else
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            //Preparar el DataAdapter para el uso del comando en la BD
            objAdapter.SelectCommand = objCmd; //El DataAdapter Utiliza el Command para la transacción
            objAdapter.Fill(objDts);//Realizar la transacción en la BD y el llenado del DataSet/Datatable
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strError = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
#endregion
}
}
```

Comment: `guardarPQR` isn't the problem, it's the `clsConexionBD` - specifically, the `SQL` property. Show the code for that instead.

Comment: The line `objCnx.SQL = strSQL` is failing. Please show the definition of that class

Comment: ok, there is the code. Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that there is a problem with the setter for `SQL` in the `clsConexionBD` class. Can you post the complete code of THAT class?

Comment: ok, there is all library libconexionBD

Comment: I have used your code and got no exception. Clean your solution and build it. If the problem persists remove the library reference in your project and re add it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Never ever (and I mean it!) use string concatenation to put parameters into queries. Learn about parameterized queries as long as you are new to this and before bad habits settle in.

Comment: Ok sorry, but i don't understand why, these parameters are privates and i have public properties for set and get these parameters. They never go to the SQL sentence directly, i know that is dangerous, if that what you means. 

With the other topic, I cleaned it up and rebuilt and nothing also, i deleted the reference and i do it again and nothing